# How item preview component should be structured in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let us assume we have to design some component in React. We want to design an item preview page. We have some list, let's say list of books in a bookshop, and then we click on an item, and navigate to book preview. This is the component we want to design.

More often than not, the beginners will start with single `BookPreviewComponent.js` file. They'll put some JSX to display a book title, image and description, and start to write a logic to get book details from web service or they'll connect the component to Redux store.

So this:

```
___________________________________
|                                 |
|   The old man and the sea       |
|   Ernest Hemingway              |
|                                 |
|   |------------|   description  |
|   | xx image xx|       of       |
|   | xx image xx|     a book     |
|   | xx image xx|                |
|   |------------|                |
|                                 |
|_________________________________|
```

Will usually transform to something like that:

```
import Card, { CardContent, CardHeader, CardMedia } from "material-ui/Card";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const styles = {
  card: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: theme.breakpoints.values.lg - theme.spacing.unit * 6,
    margin: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    },
  };

class BookPreviewComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    const { classes, bookData } = this.props;

    return (
      <div >
        {bookData && (
          <Card className={classes.card}>
             <CardHeader title={bookData.title} />
             etc...
             BUT HERE'S A LOT OF STUFF
          </Card>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

BookPreviewComponent .propTypes = {
  bookData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export const BookPreviewComponent = connect(
  state => ({
    bookData: state.bookblah
  }),
  { something else}
));
```

We can obviously create multiple components like `BookPreviewDescriptionComponent`, but they actually aren't real components because they won't be used anywhere else, outside of BookPreviewComponent.

We can generate small functions which will return parts of the component. But it helps just a bit.

So how are complex projects organized in this area? How can we design such a preview page to be clean and maintainable? How to design such a component to achieve readability and maintainability at the same time?

Comment: `they actually aren't real components because they won't be used anywhere else` is NOT the definition of a "real" component.  Reusability is a feature, not a requirement.  I generally find myself starting with the single component like you said and when I notice that it's getting too cluttered, or there are parts of the code that only relate to a certain area, I break that out into another component.  Let's say that you want to add a tooltip to the preview: instead of having to dig through 1000+ lines in a single file, you can go directly to your `BookCover` component and add it there.

Comment: @larz To some extent I agree, but to me these things should be let's say sub-classes, perhaps extracted to other files, but not just the same as all the other components. Anyway - how about the issues with state management then? We had one component written by some developer which had every line of the form  in a separate component. The overhead related to passing the state was monstrous. Do you have any experience with it? Any solution?

Comment: This Q is to wide - it all depends. Making every form element a separate component just to render it can be a premature optimization. Managing (passing where?) state depends on needs/specific implementation (formik/redux-form/local state/global redux). Array of fields/types/validation conditions, parametrized components ... there is many ways to handle this.

Comment: @xadm The general question "how to divide page to components", yes it's too wide. However I believe that this simple example can be processed in a neat way of decomposition to the components to show the bigger picture.

Comment: There is no general rule - it's depends on complexity - when it looks too complex it's time to refactor. Extraction to rendering methods is simpler as there is no passing state/props. Separate components OTOH gives you more flexibility. It's more about easier (future) management.